# Alias compiles with msvc but rejected by gcc

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, alias

I have written the following code(that uses typedef), which [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/e4aMh9j5f) with microsoft visual studio but not with gcc and clang.

```
using type = int(int)&; 
using type2 = type&;   //compiles with msvc but rejcted in gcc and clang
```

Gcc says `cannot declare reference to qualified reference type` but msvc accepts it.

Is this another bug of msvc or the program is well-formed?

Comment: clang does not accept it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given program is **ill-formed** because if a function-type has reference qualifier then we cannot create a reference to that function-type as per [dcl.ref](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref):

> [Note 4: **Forming a reference to function type is ill-formed if the function type has cv-qualifiers or a ref-qualifier;** see [dcl.fct].
> — end note]

---

And since `type1=int(int)&` is a function type with a reference-qualifier, we cannot create a reference to `type1` as you're trying to do in `type2`.

Thus, *msvc is wrong* here.